# Created and Last Change Data

Tags: joomla, database, datatables

Created and where is the Last Change data held?

Can I get information about the table location in SQL.

[image]

**System:**

- Joomla! 3.9.10
- CiviCRM 5.18.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in civicrm_log. Entity_id matches civicrm_contact.id and entity_table='civicrm_contact'. Modified_id is the contact id of who modified it.

Or if you have detailed logging turned on there's also entries in the log_civicrm_xxx tables.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the civicrm_contact table

Comment: There are created_date and modified_date tables in civicrm_contact. But there is no user information created and modified.